# Math question - specifying the range of ln

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

The original problem is this:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{2x}\ln \frac{1}{n}\sum_1^n {e^{kx}} = 20$$

Find out the value of $n$, which is a natural number.

But I'm having a bit of trouble solving this problem.

My problem is that I think that this question can be interpreted in two ways.
Since there is no brackets limiting the range of the $\ln$, I believe it can be interpreted as both :

1)
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{2x}\ln \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\sum_1^n {e^{kx}} = 20
$$

2)
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{2x}\ln \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_1^n {e^{kx}}\right) = 20
$$

If I interpret the problem as 2), the value of $n$ becomes $79$.
If I interpret the problem as 1), I can't get the value of $n$.

Am I right in assuming that all two of my interpretations are correct?

What I mean is, just like $\cos x \cos x$ is different from $\cos(x \cos x)$, shouldn't the range of the ln be specified using brackets?
Without these brackets, can this equation be interpreted in two ways, just like I did?

And if my first interpretation is correct, could anyone please explain in detail why ln and sigma can be diverged?
I certainly learned it at some point at school, but I don't exactly remember the specific details.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  In the first interpretation, the limit diverges.  And in the second, $n=79$ is correct.

Comment: What exactly is the standard for diverging the ln and sigma?

Comment: Moral lesson (for the problem poser and not the OP): when in doubt, parenthesize.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I know that in cases like this, the ln and sigma should be considered apart. But are there any specific standards or rules regarding these kinds of problem?